# Laravel Authentication using Ldap active directory

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I'm trying to use Ldap active directory to login users to a system I'm developing using laravel.
I installed LdapRecord package to deal with Ldap and the connection was established successfully. However, when I try to login I get this error:

`TypeError Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct(): Argument #2 ($provider) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\clearance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 125`

This is my config/auth.php file to configure LdapRecord

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'ldap',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
        //     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        // ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\User::class,
            'rules' => [],
            'database' => [
                'model' => App\User::class,
                'sync_passwords' => false,
                'sync_attributes' => [
                    'name' => 'cn',
                    'AD_INDEX' => 'samaccountname',
                ],
            ],
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

This is my UserController.php file where the login code goes inside the index function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $username = $request -> username;
        $password = $request -> password;
        $credentials = [
            'samaccountname' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        ];
        
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();
        
            return view('dashboard')->with([
                'message' => "Welcome back, {$user->name}"
            ]);
        }else{
            return view('welcome')->with([
                'message' => "Couldn't login"
            ]);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And this is my User Model file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\LdapAuthenticatable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\AuthenticatesWithLdap;

class User extends Authenticatable implements LdapAuthenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, AuthenticatesWithLdap;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I really appreciate if you can help to solve this error.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, You should change your provider name in config/auth.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'ldap',
    ],
```

but your provider is called users

```
'providers' => [
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
        //     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        // ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
```

That is why You're giving null to SessionGuard::__construct()